# Jmeter cache manager not working on localhost

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am using Jemeter 5.4.1 and I have an HttpRequest sampler pointing to localhost. I also have the Number of threads set to 1
Loop Count to 100

When I add cache manager, the execution stops after only 1 sample run even though I have set the loop count to 100. But when I turn off the cache manage, the loop works.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's wrong with your configuration without seeing the full response, how [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter) are being returned exactly and what are response [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Try unticking `Use Cache-Control/Expires header`

> Additionally, if the "Use Cache-Control/Expires header" option is selected, then the Cache-Control/Expires value is checked against the current time. If the request is a GET request, and the timestamp is in the future, then the **sampler returns immediately, without requesting the URL from the remote server**. This is intended to emulate browser behaviour.